# Why does this work?Does the ANSI translate values that are written in hex "form" into their decimal equal when used in mathematical functions?

Tags: c

For example,if i were to compile and run this code,it would work perfectly.My question is,how exactly does it work.How does the compiler divide, for example the hex number AF3F6F9F with the number 2 and give out a result that is satisfactory?

Here's an example program:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c, d, e, f;
    printf("Insert MAC address in hex form: ");
    scanf("%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f);
    if ((a == 0xff) && (b == 0xff) && (c == 0xff) && (d == 0xff) && (e == 0xff) && (f == 0xff))
    {
        printf("This is a broadcast address\n");
    }
    else if ((a % 2) == 0) { printf("This is a unicast address\n"); }
    else if ((a % 2) != 0)
    {
        printf("This is a multicast address\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post text as images. Please don't post images, unless they are images. How am I to copy the code and compile and run it?

Comment: The problem is that "Here's the code" doesn't work well. Search engines won't find the actual code, and people who _could_ explain the problem won't be able to (or inclined to) follow the link. Some people assume, for example, that a link to an external website is an attempt to push malware onto their machine. It is far easier for __you__ to copy and paste the code into the question than for other users to enter it, or read it. And only one person has to do the work!

Comment: I couldnt really understand the posting format's rules so i figuted a way around it.Here is the code


#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int a,b,c,d,e,f;
printf("Insert MAC address in hex form: ");
scanf("%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e,&f);
if((a == 0xff)&&(b == 0xff)&&(c == 0xff)&&(d == 0xff)&&(e == 0xff)&&(f == 0xff))
{
 printf("This is a broadcast address\n");
}
else if((a%2) == 0)
{
 printf("This is a unicast address\n");
}
else if((a%2) != 0)
{
 printf("This is a multicast address\n");
}
return 0;
}

Comment: Please edit your question and do not post code in comments. It is not readable.

Comment: How do you define result as `satisfactory`? What is an un-`satisfactory` result?

Comment: Explain what you want to do, and how. Give inputs, outputs, and possibly expected outputs.

Answer (score 1):

> the hex number

There is no 'hex number'. There is hexadecimal *representation* of a number. The hexadecimal representation of a number is `AF3F6F9F` and is equal to binary representation `10101111001111110110111110011111` and is equal to decimal representation is `2940170143` and is equal to represenatation in base of 3 `21120220110010012111`. Currently the widespread computers use binary representation for numbers. But it may change.

> How does the compiler divide

You have written the code so the compiler does not divide the numbers. The compiler generates the machine instructions that are used to divide the numbers once your program is executed. So your program divides the numbers, not the compiler.

> example the hex number AF3F6F9F with the number 2

For example on x86-64 compatible architecture a valid compiler for the following code:

```
int f(int a, int b) {
    return a % b;
}
```

can generate the following machine instructions:

```
f:
        mov     eax, edi
        cdq
        idiv    esi
        mov     eax, edx
        ret
```

As one can see the instruction `idiv` is used to divide numbers, the instruction stands for [signed divide](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/IDIV.html) and indeed divides the numbers.

> give out a result that is satisfactory?

You as the user of your machine trust that the compiler generates valid machine code that is correctly parsed by your processor and you also trust your processor to give correct results when using instructions used to divide numbers. The results will be "satisfactory" (in terms of valid mathematical result) as long as your machine will properly work.

Comment: Not bad... I like the base 3 ;-). You could emphasize more that a program is *ascii text* and that the "representations" you talk about are different *text representations*  of values which in turn may be stored in a number of different ways in the computer's memory and registers (which usually does not concern us when we program in C; this abstraction is actually one of the main reasons the language was invented in the first place). Except when you say "the widespread computers use binary representation"... that's not text any longer, it's the digital representation in memory or register.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that any number is being stored in binary, so whenever you call the output, the print function will format that number in the numeric system you desire.

Comment: This is good, as far as it goes. The OP also asked about "entering numbers in hex"